# Read groups of N adjacent elements from an array

Tags: java, arrays

[A, B, C, D, E, F]

I need to get adjacent values from above array.

Adjacent count can vary
say

if adjcnt = 2

Then I should get like this

```
 tuple 1 = A,B
 tuple 2 = C,D
 tuple 3 = E,F
```

If adjcnt = 3

```
 tuple 1 = A,B,c
 tuple 2 = D,E,F
```

My code

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 if(i < adjcnt){
   if(i==0){
     csv = arr[i];
   }
   else{
         csv += ","+arr[i];
   }
}
 System.out.println("csv---> "+csv);
}
```

This prints only 2 elements. I need to loop till my arr is empty

Some where my logic is not right.
Please Advice

Comment: Why `tuple 1.5 = B,C` is not a solution if  `adjcnt = 2`?

Comment: A simple imperative method that is easy to understand is an inner loop variable with a discrete variable. Then the outer loop is `i = 0; i < arr.length; i += adjcnt` and the inner loop if `j = 0; j < adjcnt; j++` and finally: `arr[i + j]`. Make sure to deal with cases when the array length is not a multiple of `adjcnt`.

Comment: If adjcnt  is 4 or 5 then what do you want?

Comment: if adjcnt=2 and array is [A, B, C, D, E] then what output you will expect

Comment: @AnwayKulkarni: My data will be like pairs if 2 then my array will contain excat values were I will be able to group them

Comment: Maybe you would like to try modulus (%) instead

Comment: oh yes right. % will work fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your this code:-

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 if(i < adjcnt){
   if(i==0){
     csv = arr[i];
   }
   else{
         csv += ","+arr[i];
   }
}
 System.out.println("csv---> "+csv);
}
```

to the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 if((i % adjcnt) < adjcnt){
   if((i % adjcnt)==0){
     csv = arr[i];
   }
   else{
         csv += ","+arr[i];
   }
}
 System.out.println("csv---> "+csv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int i = 0;
    int adjacent = 2;

    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        if( i% adjacent == 0 ) {
            printf("\n");
        }   
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well,, its a java question but still applicable:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way too.

```
int adjcnt = 3;
String[] arr = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};
for(int i=0; i< arr.length; i= i + adjcnt){
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i, i+adjcnt)));
   //here it will copy your original array between given indexes. 
}
```

out put:

```
[A, B, C]
[D, E, F]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unmesha, you can use the following code for your expected output

```
public class Adjacent {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char[] test = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
        int adjcnt = 3;
        StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
        int tuplecount = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
            if (i % adjcnt == 0 || i == 0) {
                if (i != 0)
                    csv.append("\n");
                csv.append("tuple ");
                csv.append(tuplecount);
                csv.append("=");
                csv.append(test[i]);
            } else {
                csv.append(",");
                csv.append(test[i]);
            }

        }
        System.out.println(csv.toString());
    }
}
```

Please update me if this code works out for you